# Any difference for how to calculate remainder?

Tags: c++, c, performance

Lets suppose that a = 2^k
is there any difference in terms of performance or correctness between `int c = b%a` and `int c = b & (a-1)`?

Comment: Assuming you meant `unsigned int c`, and both `b` and `a` are also `unsigned int`, and the value of `a` is known to the compiler, and you turned the optimizer on, then no, there is not.  If any of the above are not the case then yes, there could be.

Comment: Depends on the whether the compiler can prove that `a = 2^k`. If so, then it may be able to generate the same assembly for both snippets. If not, then the second snippet is (typically) faster (since division is (typically) a very expensive operation).

Comment: @user3386109: Even if the compiler can prove `a = 2^k`, it should not generate the same assembly for both expressions. `-1%16` is −1, but `-1&15` is 15 (with two’s complement).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, my comment was in addition to zwol's, not in place of. If either `a` or `b` is negative, then the second snippet has either undefined or implementation defined behavior, and shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For two’s complement `int` and `a` a power of two, `b % a` equals `b & a-1` if and only if `b` is non-negative or a multiple of `a`.

As a consequence, a compiler can replace `b % a` by `b & a-1` only if it knows `b` is non-negative or knows it is a multiple of `a`. (In the latter case, it should replace the expression with zero.) On typical current processors, an AND and a subtract instruction will be at least as fast, and often faster, than a remainder (divide) instruction, so `b & a-1` is preferred, and the programmer seeking performance should use it if they know the conditions are satisfied, unless they are sure the compiler will generate an AND for `b % a` or they also want the quotient `b/a`. (If the quotient is desired, the compiler must generate a divide instruction, and processors typically provide the remainder along with the quotient.)

Of course, the compiler can be assured that `b` is non-negative by making it an `unsigned int`. Ensuring the compiler knows that `a` is a power of two is more complicated, unless `a` is a constant.

Comment: I suppose the compiler could pay attention to an `assert(1==__builtin_popcount(a))` (if it understands GCC built-ins) or `assert(a && !(a&(a-1)))`, even if assertions are disabled...